# Setting custom gradients on TensorFlow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, gradient-descent

I am using a really simple neural network with the latest version of tensorflow 2.0, on a jupyter notebook running python 3.7.0.
From a matrix M, the NN computes a parameter P. Then I have a function F which from P computes another matrix M' that I want to use in my loss function.

I understand that TF2.0 automatically gives me the gradients from M to P.
I also have calculated the gradients from P to M', which I want to plug in using the chain rule in order to have the full gradients from M to M'.

I have searched on the TF site for documentation but didn't find any response to my issue. How should I proceed?

Edit: The code I am trying to make work is the following:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

# Add the layers
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="relu"))

# The loss method
loss_object = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()
# The optimize
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
# This metrics is used to track the progress of the training loss during the training
train_loss = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name='train_loss')


def train_step(Data): #Data is: Blurred image; blurr matrix; max(true image); gvar; true image
    img = Data[4]
    MainGaussian_init(Data)
    for _ in range (K):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            Xip= model( M )
            MainGaussian_1_U () #Computes M' from Xip aka P 
            print ("img=", img)
            loss= loss_object(M_true, M2) #with M2 as M'
            print ("loss=", loss)
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
        print (gradients)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))
        train_loss(loss)
```

Let me know if any of this needs to be made any clearer!

Comment: Please provide any code you may have written.

Comment: I provided some code, let me know if you have anything to say about it!

Comment: As long as you use `Xip` in `MainGaussian_1_U`, you should get the complete gradients from M to M' directly when you call `tape.gradient()`